# Android webview does not take bad url

Tags: android, android-webview

WebView does not take url if they are bad formated ??

For example good url format `http://www.youtube.com/embed/KeSzOIUJ4xY?rel=0` and
bad url format `//player.vimeo.com/video/142545652?badge=0`

Is there a way to accept the following bad url as browsers do ??

Answer (score 0):

No android web view didnt take a bad formatted url..

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("https")
    .authority("www."+YOUR_STRING+".com")
    .appendPath("turtles")
    .appendPath("types")
    .appendQueryParameter("type", "1")
    .appendQueryParameter("sort", "relevance")
    .fragment("section-name");
String myUrl = builder.build().toString();
```

But you can play with above code.

Comment: The problem is that i can have any url authority